# Django how to save a custom formset

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, formset

I've written the following custom formset, but for the life of me I don't know how to save the form. I've searched the Django docs and done extensive searches, but no one solution works. Lots of rabbit holes, but no meat ;-) Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
// views.py partial //

@login_required

def add_stats(request, group_slug, team_id, game_id, template_name = 'games/stats_add_form.html'):

    if request.POST:

        formset = AddStatsFormSet(group_slug=group_slug, team_id=team_id, game_id=game_id, data=request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():

            formset.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('games_game_list'))

        else:

            formset = TeamStatFormSet(group_slug=group_slug, team_id=team_id, game_id=game_id)

        return render_to_response(template_name, {'formset': formset,})


// modles.py partial //

class PlayerStat(models.Model):

    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, verbose_name=_(u'sport event'),)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, verbose_name=_(u'player'),)
    stat = models.ForeignKey(Stat, verbose_name=_(u'statistic'),)
    total = models.CharField(_(u'total'), max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('player stat')
        verbose_name_plural = _('player stats')
        db_table     = 'dfusion_playerstats'

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % self.player


// forms.py

class TeamStatForm(forms.Form):

    total = forms.IntegerField()


class BaseTeamStatsFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.group_slug = kwargs['group_slug']
        self.team_id = kwargs['team_id']
        self.game_id = kwargs['game_id']
        self.extra = len(Stat.objects.filter(group__slug=self.group_slug))
        del kwargs['group_slug']
        del kwargs['game_id']
        del kwargs['team_id']
        super(BaseTeamStatsFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(BaseTeamStatsFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields["stat"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Stat.objects.filter(group__slug=self.group_slug))
        form.fields["game"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Game.objects.all())
        form.fields["team"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Team.objects.all())
        form.fields["game"].initial = self.game_id
        form.fields["team"].initial = self.team_id

TeamStatFormSet = formset_factory(TeamStatForm, BaseTeamStatsFormSet)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your custom forms, you'll need to add a save() method that stuffs the form data into your models as needed.  All of the data entered in the form will be available in a hash called cleaned_data[].

For example:

```
def save(self):
    teamStat = TeamStat(game_id=self.cleaned_data['game_id'],team_id=self.cleaned_data['team_id'])
    teamStat.save()
    return teamStat
```

Comment: Glad it helped, I'm just starting on my first Django project and working through these issues also.

Answer (score 3):

Only model forms and formsets come with a `save()` method. Regular forms aren't attached to models, so you have to store the data yourself. [How to save a formset?](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/fd20b860b7d9b00e) from the Django mailing list has an example of saving data from a regular formset.

Edit: You can always add a `save()` method to a regular form or formset as gbc suggests. They just don't have one built-in.

I don't see a `TeamStat` model in your code snippets, but if you had one, your `forms.py` should look something like this:

```
class TeamStatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    total = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = TeamStat


class BaseTeamStatsFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.group_slug = kwargs['group_slug']
        self.team_id = kwargs['team_id']
        self.game_id = kwargs['game_id']
        self.extra = len(Stat.objects.filter(group__slug=self.group_slug))
        del kwargs['group_slug']
        del kwargs['game_id']
        del kwargs['team_id']
        super(BaseTeamStatsFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(BaseTeamStatsFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields["stat"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Stat.objects.filter(group__slug=self.group_slug))
        form.fields["game"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Game.objects.all())
        form.fields["team"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Team.objects.all())
        form.fields["game"].initial = self.game_id
        form.fields["team"].initial = self.team_id

TeamStatFormSet = modelformset_factory(TeamStatForm, BaseTeamStatsFormSet)
```

See [Creating forms from models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) from the Django docs